# Possible to bypass servicestack's authentication mechanisms for non standard authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, servicestack

My authentication mechanism is in a way different it cannot fit into 1 of ServiceStack's current authentication methods (even overriding method 'TryAuthenticate' does not provide a solution). So would it be possible to authenticate from some arbitrary ServiceStack service?

To give an example:

1. I open a plain old HTML login page (I am using Angular for the record).
2. I login in and call my custom ServiceStack service in order to send the non-standard credentials to the server (of course using Angular's http directive).
3. I validate the credentials myself. If correct I like to hook up into servicestack authentication mechanism and probably have to send back a ServiceStack authentication cookie to the browser. Am I correct?

If someone can make 3 work I can call ServiceStack services which have the authenticate attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be allowed through the `[Authenticate]` attribute, it needs [any one of the registered AuthProviders](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/d20820f4be7de60e1519f3586639d30d5a778f25/src/ServiceStack/AuthenticateAttribute.cs#L73) `IsAuthorized()` to return `true`, i.e:

```
public class CustomAuthProvider : AuthProvider
{
    public CustomAuthProvider()
    {
        this.Provider = "custom";
    }

    public override bool IsAuthorized(
        IAuthSession session, IAuthTokens tokens, Authenticate request=null)
    {
        return true; //custom logic to verify if this session is authenticated
    }

    public override object Authenticate(
        IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, Authenticate request)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new CustomUserSession(),
    new IAuthProvider[] {
        new CustomAuthProvider()
    }));
```

In your Custom Authentication Service you should also save the Users Session with `IsAuthenticated=true`, e.g:

```
public object Any(CustomAuth request)
{
    //Authenticate User
    var session = base.SessionAs<CustomUserSession>();
    session.IsAuthenticated = true;
    this.SaveSession(session);        
}
```

Comment: I have changed 'return true; //custom logic to verify if this session is authenticated' to 'return session.IsAuthenticated;'. I first did not understand the 'CustomUserSession' class but I found it at link: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions. It is a class derived from 'AuthUserSession'. I tested it and it seems to work!

Many thanks from a devoted ServiceStack user!

Comment: @Stackbever Yep `CustomUserSession` can be any type that inherits from `AuthUserSession`, since you're looking to use your own Authentication I expected you'll also want to use a Custom AuthUserSession with additional custom fields.

Comment: I never used ServiceStack authentication before and when reading the Session article I like to know if the above solution also works for the 'Remember me' scenario (permanent vs temporary session). So I tried: 1. 'this.SaveSession(session, new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0, 0));', 2. Authenticate, 3. Call secure service, yep it works!, 4. Close browser, 5. Start browser and call the secure service again but fails. Was hoping it would remember the session somehow.

Comment: @Stackbever If you want to remember the Session you need to save the session against the permanent session id in your CustomAuth Service. You can copy this statement from the existing Auth Service to [register the clients preference of using either temporary vs permanent session](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/d20820f4be7de60e1519f3586639d30d5a778f25/src/ServiceStack/Auth/AuthenticateService.cs#L96).

Comment: Could you help me on this subject because I do not understand how to save against a permanent session id. If I debug 'var session = base.SessionAs<CustomUserSession>();' is this id generated a temporary id? Should I use another method? And I cannot find permanent/temporary option on the 'SaveSession' method. Or do you mean I should use another store for the session (I use Redis for my 'normal' data by the way)

Comment: @Stackbever Please copy the code I linked to above, that's what's used to determine whether to record the preference on whether to save against the Temporary or Permanent Session. This preference is saved in the Users `ss-opt` Cookie, e.g. `ss-opt=temp` or `ss-opt=perm`.

Comment: Thank you very much, just tested it and it works! Completely misunderstood your link.